# Выполнить функцию php по истечению времени

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Ребят, пишу аукцион.
Как бы покупка должна отдаться по истечению какого-то времени, а отдавать ее должна какая-то функция, которая должна выполниться в момент истечения времени.
Я рассматривал варианты **создать задачу CRON**, но запускать ее каждую сикунду это нереально для сервера (мне кажется), **второй вариант**: запускать эту функцию "проверки" фоном при каждом действии пользователя, что тоже нагрузит сервер.
**Что посоветуете?**

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужна точность до секунды?

Comment: @Fike ну когда покупка падает в "покупки" по истечению времени то наверное это хорошо

Comment: @igolka97, я ничего не понял из сказанной фразы, но начальном этапе, думаю, можно выполнять проверку раз в минуту (и, соответственно, время окончания задавать в минтуах без секунд). Второй вариант абсолютно неработоспособен при небольшой (или наоборот, большой) посещаемости, третьим будет написать демона, который сам себе будет выставлять таймеры и проводить необходимые операции.

Comment: @Fike демон это ад :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К каждому аукциону в базу пишите timestamp. И если время на серваке "перевалило" за timestamp то выводите его статус как закрытый. Аналогично при генерации ЛК (личном кабинете) юзеров кто делал ставки на этот ID аукциона, если сервертайм "перетёк" за timestamp и у этого юзера "самая высокая ставка" (любое нужное вам условие) => продано.

Ну и раз в сутки прогонять базу кроном (скажем часа в 4 утра от ЦА) на удаление(скрытие, выставление статуса) аукционам. Или вместо крона использовать MySQL Event Scheduler (http://habrahabr.ru/post/123391/)